# How to rename a blob file using powershell

Tags: powershell, blob, azure-data-factory

seemingly simple task. I just want to rename a blob file, I know I have to copy it to rename or something, then delete the original but this is proving tricky. I have created the storage context (New-AzureStorageContext), and got the blob (Get-AzureStorageBlob), and found Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy, but how to I actually rename it?

I'd like to do this within the same container if possible as well. Ideally I'd run it in an Azure Runbook and call it using a webhook I Azure Data Factory v2. I did try to rename the file using 'Add Dynamic Content' in the copy job sink in DFv2, but I don't think you can. By the way, I just want to append the date to the existing file name. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my  `Rename-AzureStorageBlob`convenience function:

```
function Rename-AzureStorageBlob
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)]
        [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob]$Blob,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$NewName
    )

  Process {
    $blobCopyAction = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy `
        -ICloudBlob $Blob.ICloudBlob `
        -DestBlob $NewName `
        -Context $Blob.Context `
        -DestContainer $Blob.ICloudBlob.Container.Name

    $status = $blobCopyAction | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState

    while ($status.Status -ne 'Success')
    {
        $status = $blobCopyAction | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    }

    $Blob | Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Force
  }
}
```

It accepts the blob as pipeline input so you can pipe the result of the Get-AzureStorageBlob to it and just provide a new name:

```
$connectionString= 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName....'
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connectionString

Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container 'MyContainer' -Context $storageContext -Blob 'myBlob.txt'|
    Rename-AzureStorageBlob -NewName 'MyNewBlob.txt'
```

To append the date to the existing file name you can use something like:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container 'MyContainer' -Context $storageContext -Blob 'myBlob.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
$_ | Rename-AzureStorageBlob -NewName "$($_.Name)$(Get-Date -f "FileDateTime")" }
```

Further reading: [Rename Azure Storage Blob using PowerShell](https://about-azure.com/2018/02/13/rename-azure-storage-blob-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I did see this, but I don't know where to run it? By which I mean, where to a put the function? In an Azure Function? I looked at those, but it seemed like only C# was accepted, I saw no option to use PowerShell, or do I put the function in an Automation runbook? Or is it used in a Data Factory custom activity? Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can either use Azure Function which supports PowerShell (in preview) or use a Automation Runbook.