# Rename azure blob with specific condition

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a Storage account with Test container and this container contains 24 folders and each folder contains `n` numbers of blobs. What i want is to rename all the folder and sub blob in Pic 1 to exactly like in Pic 2.

[image]
[image]

I've used this rename script: 
[How to rename a blob file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625603/how-to-rename-a-blob-file-using-powershell)

But above script is useful for one or two blobs plus this script doesn't renames folder(this can be solved by copying the blob to new location) where as in my case i have `n` blob which i tried to tackle with:

```
$textinfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
$text2=($textinfo.ToTitleCase($text)).Split(" ")
```

But this is also not helping since it will rename *exchangerate* to *Exchangerate* but not to *ExchangeRate*(and this is the real requirement).
I thought of this:

```
foreach($file in $text)
    {
        Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'test' -Context $storageContext -Blob $text|
        Rename-AzStorageBlob -NewName ''
    }
```

But then new name(parameter) i'm not able to make it dynamic. How to approach this?

Comment: is the new name a  fixed value ?

Comment: Do you have a mapping where you can lookup oldname -> newname? If not, how you expext to change the string from exchangerate to ExchangeRate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rename a blob from `exchangerate` to `ExchangeRate`, there is no automatic way for this.

To do that, as Martin mentioned, you'd better have a mapping where you can lookup `exchangerate` -> `ExchangeRate` (and also for all other names contain more than one words).

Otherwise, your code doesn't know whether a letter in the new blob name should be uppercase or not.

Answer (score 0):

Modified my code something like this

```
##Lookup.
$hash = $null
##Hash table with keys in Lowercase and values in Uppercase
$hash = @{...}

##Renaming the files.
$file = $null
$file1 = $null
foreach($file in $text)
    {
       if($hash.Values -eq $file)
            { 
                Write-Host 'Old name' $file
                foreach($file1 in $hash.Values)
                    {
                        if($file -eq $file1)
                            {
                                Write-Host 'New name' $file1
                                Get-AzStorageBlob -Container 'test' -Context $storageContext -Blob $file| Rename-AzStorageBlob -NewName $file1 
                            }
                    }
            }      

    }
```

So this is working for me.