# Extract text from filename in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, expression

I have file names like this 20200405_Apples.xlsx or Bananas_20230423.txt where date can be at the front or at the end.
I want to remove the dates and get the file names like this Apples.xlsx or Bananas.txt.
How do I extract that in an expression in ADF in the copy activity. I want to use this in the sink in copy activity. Please can someone help.

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

The source_name is of the kind 20200405_Apples.xlsx or Bananas_20230423.txt, comprising of 3 parts - date, fruit, extension. So, firstly obtain the 3 parts using split function and set in 3 different variables.

[image]

[image: Finding part1]

[image: Finding part2]

[image: Finding extension]
Where we don't know the order of date and fruit. It can be date_fruit.extension or fruit_date.extension.

Here, for input(source_name) of Bananas_20230423.txt,

```
part1='Bananas'
part2='20230423'
extension='txt'
```

There isn't an explicit function to check whether a string is date or just alphabets. So, I used greater function in ADF dynamic expressions.

Greater function checks if 1st value is greater than 2nd to return True and False otherwise. Comparing Part1 with Part2 i.e. 'Bananas' with '20230423', returns True. In case of 20200405_Apples.xlsx, it will compare '20200405' with 'Apples' and return False. Wrap it in an If condition so on true you will know that part1 is the fruit and on false, part2 is the fruit. Concatenate with extension we previously obtained and you have your sink name.
[image]

Edit - Adding some info from comments. The greater function doesn't work for multiple data types. The two values need to be of same data type. So, we can't compare string with integer or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks Yash for providing the detailed answer. Just one question, how does greater work when you compare an integer with string? How come comparing Bananas with 20230423, returns True?

Comment: Hey @sparc, welcome. I can't confirm from any documentation but from my testing it seems like it is comparing the ASCII values. The greater function doesn't work for multiple data types. The two values need to be of same data type. So, we can't compare string with integer. And, if you check how we extract the different parts- we split the source_name string to get a string. So, it is comparing 'Banana' with string '20230423' and not integer 20230423. If this answer has worked then pls mark it as accepted so that it is helpful to others too.

Comment: Hi @Yash Tamakuwala. The names can also be like this apples_grapes_20230204.csv or 20230102_bananas_pear.txt. How to get it working in those cases?

Comment: In that case, you are better off going trying to get source system to agree on a standard. There's nothing stopping this to go to date_fruit1.....fruit100.csv or fruit1_...fruit100_date.csv. One approach could be to copy the files as is in copy activity and then invoke a function App in powershell and run that to rename files. You want to cater to wide range of scenarios and it is going to get pretty complicated and messy with ADF dynamic expressions. 
Refer something like - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53625935